# java.sql.SQLException when trying to connect to azure database using spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, azure

I have a spring-boot project in which i try to connect to an azure database. When i run the application i'm having this weird error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Driver:SQLServerDriver:2 returned null for URL:jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

This is my application.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=production
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

spring.datasource.platform=jdbc:sqlserver://spring-boot-intro.database.windows.net:1433;database=spring-boot-intro;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
spring.datasource.username=fabio
spring.datasource.password=*my password*
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

These are my dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>slqjdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you have use `spring.datasource.platform` instead of `spring.datasource.url` for the datasource URL in the `application.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message you provided `return null for URL: JDBC: h2: mem: testdb's prompt`, refer to [the document of h2database](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases), which appears to be omitted from the **url** parameter.

In addition, I observed some issues with importing sqlserver jar packages in your maven pom.xml.

Please refer to the following configuration in the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-java):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.1.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```